# Drawing Line Chart in BIRT

Tags: report, birt

I've faced some difficulties for drawing a linear chart in BIRT (4.4) that I hoped to use your experience for solving this problem.

Actually I've a DataSet like this:

Date - Name - Value

2015-01-01  Alex  5
2015-01-02  Alex  7
2015-01-03  Alex  12
2015-01-01  Brian  15
2015-01-02  Brian  70
2015-01-03  Brian  2
2015-01-01  John  11
2015-01-02  John  3
2015-01-03  John  8

What I'd like to accomplish is to draw three lines for Brian, Alex and John .. so that the X-Axis shows the Dates and Y-Axis shows the Values.

It really confuses me .. could somebody help me out ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, All I had to do was Group the Y-Plot data with "Optional Y-Axis grouping" feature. ;)

Comment: I am trying to plot same kind of records as a line chat but confused in eclipse birt chart plugin. Can you please help me how you draw your chart. Here is a link of my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329664/how-to-create-line-chart-from-birt-chat-plugin-in-eclipse